# ubuntu 14.04 alt+shift and Eclipse problem

Tags: shortcut-keys, eclipse

I have US, and Greek layout options and I switch between these using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

1.I use eclipse and I am very used to pressing alt+shift+r in order to use an application's shortcut. In ubuntu I can't do this since the moment I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, the layout changes and I can't proceed to the shortcut

1.If the selected layout is Greek I can't make use of shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

For information see [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2013-November/037768.html) and [here (comment #221 and #232)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1226962).

It happened that there is a problem with applications which use java. I followed the things in comment #232 and did the following:

- `add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts`;
- `apt-get update`;
- installed package `gnome-settings-daemon 3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11.2ppa1`;
- installed package `unity-settings-daemon 14.04.0+14.04.20140429-0ubuntu1ppa1` (NOTE: the version is important, it's not the last version in the repositories).

Now I can change the layout without problem and use the shortcuts in java applications.